# Identifying groups with subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

I was playing around with semidirect products and tried finding a non abelian semi direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\rtimes
\mathbb{Z}_2$. I couldn't find a group that worked, and I realized this was because the non abelian groups of order 8 ($D_8$ and $Q$) didn't have $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a subgroup.

So my question is whether we can identify when a group can be expressed as a semi-direct product that includes $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. For example, how do we know if more than one group of order 20 can be written as a semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$?

(I say "more than one" because of the direct product  $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_5$, which is technically a semidirect product)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $D_8$ certainly is a semidirect product of an elementary abelian group of order $4$ ($V_4$) and a cyclic group of order $2$ ($C_2$). The action of $C_2$ on $V_4$ is essentially the action of the linear map interchanging two basis vectors in a two-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space on said space.

Comment: In general you need to count the possible actions of the group you want to form a direct product with (lets call it $G$) on $C_2 \times C_2$ up to isomorphy. That is you need to count the group homomorphisms $G \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(V_4) \cong \mathrm{GL}_2(2)$ up to conjugacy.

Comment: Maybe I'm going to say something that you find trivial, but a group has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ iff it has two different but commuting elements of order $2£.

Comment: I thought that $D_8$ was the semidirect product of $C_4$ and $C_2$. Does this mean that a group can be the result of two different semi-direct products? Thanks a lot for your comments. And, Najib, no, I hadn't considered your statement. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

But $D_8$ *does* have $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ as a subgroup: using the presentation $$D_8 = \langle a,b \mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^4 = Id\rangle$$ the subgroup generated by $a$ and $bab$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

To get a non-abelian semidirect product $(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ all you need is an order 2 isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, for example swap the two generators.

But there are no nonabelian groups of order 20 which are semidirect products of the form 
$$(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) \rtimes \text{(some order 5 group)}
$$
because the only order 5 group is cyclic and there are no order 5 automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Doesn't $D_8$ have the presentation ⟨a,b∣$a^4$=$b^2$=$=e, $a^(-1)b=ba⟩? I thought that the subgroup generated by a would be {e,a,$a^2$,$a^3$}, which is isomorphic to $C_4$.

But what you said about there being no groups of order 20 which are semidirect products of  $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris: Groups can have different presentations. My presentation and your presentation written in the form $\langle a',b \mid (a')^4 = b^2 = e, \, (a')^{-1} b = ba \rangle$ are related by $a' = ab$.

Comment: I see what you mean now, thanks.